# How to get the width of a line of multi-line text use Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Line f.e.:

```html
    <p style="width: 300px;">asdasd sa das d asd a sd as das dasdasdasdasd saddasdasdasdasd asdasdsd</p>
```

The width of P is 300px but each of the lines is smaller. I need to calculate it for each line.
Screen:
[multiline block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRiyw.png)

Comment: you may get some ideas here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late but, I had the same request, and I thought a solution. When you make a selection to a div, you can get the bounding rects, of every selection box, so, if you have multiple line you get the width and the position of every line.

```js
window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(document.querySelector("p#element"));
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); 
var rects = range.getClientRects();
console.log(rects);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know js way but you can use jquery for that:

```
   <p id="demo" style="white-space:pre">
    Line 1

    Line 2

    Line 3

    Line 4 Blah

    Line 5
    </p>
```

JQUERY:

```
  $(function(){
var text =  $.trim($('#demo').text());
// this may vary browser to browser...
var text_w_no_empty_lines = text.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n');
var lines = text_w_no_empty_lines.split('\n');
// line number you want  total - 1
var line_5 = lines[4];
// .tick { white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;display:none }
alert( $('<p class="tick">').html(line_5).appendTo('body').width() )
}
);
```

Comment: No, it did not help me. I have a block with a certain width